# How to check compatibility of packages in setup.py wihout installation?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I use a setup.py to declare the python libraries to include in the package of my solution.

Is there a way to check the libraries compatibility using setup.py without installing the package? Because for now I can detect the conflicts only when I try to install my package.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think if I were you I would try with [*dephell*](https://pypi.org/project/dephell/). I don't think it will be able to give you a clear answer without tweaking, but it might help you get a bit closer to the info you are looking for. For example you could try these commands:

```
dephell deps check --from setuppy
```

-- https://dephell.readthedocs.io/cmd-deps-check.html

or

```
dephell deps tree --from setuppy
```

-- https://dephell.readthedocs.io/cmd-deps-tree.html